# Python change dir in windows

Tags: python

I cannot understand, how to read file in different dir on Windows.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\vasyl.v\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37'
>>> Fh = open(“d:\\python\\monitor.py”, “r”)
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Can anyone explain me, how to handle Windows paths in Python 3.7.x?

Comment: You appear to be using fancy quotes. `“` vs `"`. You'll need to adjust your keyboard to use the correct, normal quotes.

Comment: `.replace('“','"').replace('”','"')` is a workaround, but its probably just better to use normal quotes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks! Perhaps you can help me with another - why I cannot read file from this path? https://i.imgur.com/aHL64ac.png

Comment: @VasiliyVegas Python 3 needs `()` brackets for `print` statements...

Comment: @RoadRunner thanks for your reply! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
with open("d:\\python\\monitor.py", "r") as infile:
    # do stuff with file here
    data = infile.readlines()
```

in the code above I used what is called a "context manager", this will automatically close the file when the operations are finished. If the code above does not read your file, then either the path is incorrect, file does not exist, or you dont have proper permissions to read the file.

Comment: Although using a context manager is good advise generally, it does not address the question at all - the error is clearly not related to not closing a file.

Comment: You are correct, I addressed the issue in the last sentence of my response when I stated "If the code above does not read your file, then either the path is incorrect, file does not exist, or you dont have proper permissions to read the file."

Comment: @mikeg nevertheless your comment was helpful in my next script steps. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!